# UImagePickerController fires warning that cause a UIView+Layout category to stop working

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app where I use a UIImagePickerController and after I close it, either taking a picture or using the cancel button, some custom UIView start to dissapear. The reason why they disappear is because their width or height become equal to 0. I can mess around with the app (is quite a big one with 4 tab bar and sever modal view controllers) and everything is fine untill a try to take a picture.
When I try to open the imagePicker I got this warning:

> warning: Tried to remove a
>   non-existent library:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.1
>   (8G4)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit

Just discovered something.
Possibly the reason why the views disappear is that a category UIView+Layout that I use stop to work after that warning. This category basically helps me to set a width/height to a view like:

- (void) setWidth:(double)value {
  CGRect frame = [self frame];
  frame.size.width = round(value);
  [self setFrame:frame];
  }

All the views that disappear have to do with this category and if I operate those changes manually the views work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same warning like you but the app crashes instead.
The reason is that I have a UIView category which has a method:

+(UIView*)firstResponder;

when I change the name of this method to

+(UIView*)theFirstResponder;

the problem went away.

I guess we should not name the methods in our category similar to the built-in method names of that class.

You may want to change your method name to something like this:

```
+ (void)changeWidth:(double)value   
{   
   CGRect frame = [self frame];   
   frame.size.width = round(value);   
   [self setFrame:frame];  
}
```

Comment: setWidth: is not a method in UIView, so there is no overwriting involved.